# how to process standart confirm window

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this code login off is faster then a browser close.

```
$(window).on('beforeunload',function(e){
    var msg = "Close window?";
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = msg;
        $('.exit').click();
        return msg;
    }
});
```

How do I add processing to select an action in the window?

```
for example:
if(true){
    $('.exit').click();
}
```

I have found a cross-browser example:
    var myEvent = window.attachEvent || window.addEventListener;
    var chkevent = window.attachEvent ? 'onbeforeunload' : 'beforeunload'; /// make IE7, IE8 compitable

```
myEvent(chkevent, function(e) { // For >=IE7, Chrome, Firefox
    var confirmationMessage = 'Are you sure to leave the page?';  // a space
    (e || window.event).returnValue = confirmationMessage;
    return confirmationMessage;
});
```

But my question is still open: how to processing chossing close or not in confirm window?

Comment: are you looking for something like this `if (confirm('Your question')) { 
 // do things if OK
}`

Comment: The `beforeunload` handler is very limited in what it's allowed to do.

Comment: Like Barmar mentioned, the `beforeunload` handler is very strict since it is built into the browsers object. I answered a similar question a while back, where the scenario was regarding changing the popup dialog to custom, and it was not possible - so I think your case is neither (or maybe open for a workaround)..

Comment: yes, something like if (confirm('Your question')) {   // do things if OK }. But it doesn't work with 'return msg'. Problem not in choosing event for close window. Problem in processing of button sumbit (confirm buttons)